# Printing the first n numbers of the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: javascript, algorithm, fibonacci-sequence

I have written a code below for printing the first n fibonacci numbers,

the code is as follows

```
var fibo = function (n){
    var num = 1, prevNum = 1, currentNum = 1, printNum = [];
    do{
        if(num == 1){
            prevNum = num;
            currentNum = num;
            printNum.push(num);
            num++;
        }else if(num == 2){
            currentNum = num;
            printNum.push(num);
            num++;
        }else{
            num = currentNum + prevNum;
            printNum.push(num);
            prevNum = currentNum;
            currentNum = num;
        }
        n--;
    }while(n >= 1);
    console.log(printNum.toString());
}

fibo(6);
fibo(10);
fibo(20);
```

The output of the above program is as follows,

```
PS D:\> node .\fibonacci.js
1,2,3,5,8,13
1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89
1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946
PS D:\>
```

Is there a better way in implementing it ?

please review my code

Comment: Please add what you used as a reference for the Fibonacci series to generate. What has prompted to first build `printNum` and only print it when the last element is computed?

Comment: (You tagged `comparative-review` - I find only one solution presented.)

Answer (score 1):

For readability, I prefer the (pythonesque?!) *destructuring assignment*
 (and array over, say, `BigUint64Array[n]`).
I do not find value added by the name suffix `Num`.
When not intending to change the meaning of `fibo` at runtime, I'd rather declare it a function.
Somehow, special cases (1, 2) crept into your implementation.
Separation of concerns would would split out logging - I kept `fibo()`s interface below:

```js
/** Return an array with the first n elements of the Fibonacci sequence.
 *  If the array is non-empty, log it to the console. */
function fibo(n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        return []
    var a = 1, b = 1,
        sequence = [b]
    while (0 < --n) {
        [a, b] = [b, a + b]
        sequence.push(b)
    }
    console.log(sequence.toString())
    return sequence
}

console.log(fibo(0))
fibo(6); fibo(10); fibo(20);
```

For JSDoc, add tags as you like

```
    * @argument n   the number of elements
    * @return       an array with the first n elements of the Fibonacci sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript number primitives and Number objects use IEEE 754 Floating-Point Arithmetic. The Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER constant represents the maximum safe integer in JavaScript (2^53 - 1). Use JavaScript BigInt to avoid floating-point approximations for large integer values. Use JavaScript BigInt to avoid printing large integer values in exponential notation.

---

Keep things simple. Why do you complicate the computation with if () else if () else?

---

A sequence of Fibonacci numbers has value independent of its String output format. Don't conflate the computation and the toString output of the sequence by doing everything in a single function.

---

---

The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) definition of Fibonacci numbers:

```
OEIS: A000045        
Fibonacci numbers: F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) with F(0) = 0 and F(1) = 1.
https://oeis.org/A000045
```

In JavaScript, a sequence of n Fibonacci numbers:

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    let fibs = [];
    let [a, b] = [BigInt(0), BigInt(1)];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        fibs.push(a);
        [a, b] = [b, a + b];
    }
    return fibs;
}

console.log(fibonacci(150).toString());
```

---

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,
. . .
,10284720757613717413913,16641027750620563662096,26925748508234281076009
```

---

An older Fibonacci number definition starts the sequence with 1, 1.

```
let [a, b] = [BigInt(1), BigInt(1)];
```

Fibonacci started the sequence with with 1, 2.

```
let [a, b] = [BigInt(1), BigInt(2)];
```

---

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     n--;
> }while(n >= 1);
> ```

You don't need to consume the input argument.  You already have an up-to-date value.

```
  } while (n > printNum.length);
```

If you start with

```
  const printNum = [1, 2];
```

You can close with

```
  return printNum.slice(0, n);
```

Then you don't need any special cases.  Just

```
  const fibs = [1, 2];
  while (fibs.length < n) {
    fibs.push(fibs[fibs.length - 1] + fibs[fibs.length - 2]);
  }

  return fibs.slice(0, n);
```

Note that this also gets rid of the redundant variables and just works on the array.